# Proper Way to Wrap Column using bash printf

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, formatting, printf

I wrote my usage function for a bash script using `printf`, however, it was so cumbersome that I imagine there *must* be an easier way than the way that I did it. I am curious to find out what it is, so I can improve for next time (only 2 args shown below to illustrate the point).

Here is the code itself:

```
 usage(){
    printf "\n\e[1m%s\x1b[0m %-5s\n" "USAGE:" "Blah Blah"
    printf "%7s \e[1m%-15s\x1b[0m %s %s\n" "" "-h" "[Optional]" "Display usage information"
    printf "%7s \e[1m%-15s\x1b[0m %s %s" "" "-ofps" "[Optional] Number of output frames per second"
    printf "%-34s %s\n" "" "Applies to the *output* video frame rate."
    exit 1
}
```

Output looks like:

```
USAGE: Blah Blah
       -h        [Optional] Display usage information
       -ofps     [Optional] Number of output frames per second                                               
                            Applies to the *output* video frame rate.
```

If there was a way of specifying that the string in the rightmost "column" should wrap around (and preserve the indent) if the length of the *entire* line were to exceed 80 characters that would be the functionality I am looking for.

I am interested in pure bash solutions, but particularly, I am interested the most in the easiest way to do this while still using `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way I typically do my Usage commands, it doesn't use printf, but it is effective. (I also use tput instead of raw escape sequences.  Check the `tput(1)` and `terminfo(5)` manual pages for details)

```
Usage="Blah Blah [-options...]

  options
  $(tput bold)-h$(tput sgr0)       Display usage information
  $(tput bold)-o<fps>$(tput sgr0)  Number of output frames per second
           Applies to the *output* video frame rate
"
```

Then, whenever I want to print it, I put:

```
echo 2>&1 "?Usage: $Usage";
exit 1
```

or some variation.  If you want to, you can add `| fmt` to the end of the echo.  That will do the word-wrapping for you. But typically, I just do the big multi-line string at the start of my script, just after the `#!/bin/env bash` to act as internal documentation as well as the usage message.

Comment: `fmt` is the solution I was looking for. Cheers.